# How to generate a missing secret_key_base on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to launch my Rails 6.0.2.1, Ruby 2.6.5 application in production using AWS EB CLI, however, I continue to encounter this issue. I've tried every solution that exists within the first two pages of Google's search results for this to no avail.

These are my error logs:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p648
  ruby-2.1.10
  ruby-2.2.10
  ruby-2.3.8
  ruby-2.4.9
  ruby-2.5.7
  ruby-2.6.5
  ruby-current ]]
  +++ RUBIES+=("$dir"/*)
  +++ for dir in '"$PREFIX/opt/rubies"' '"$HOME/.rubies"'
  +++ [[ -d /.rubies ]]
  +++ unset dir
  +++ cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.ruby_version
  ++ chruby 2.6.5
  ++ case "$1" in
  ++ local dir match
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.10
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.9
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ match=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5
  ++ for dir in '"${RUBIES[@]}"'
  ++ dir=/opt/rubies/ruby-current
  ++ case "${dir##*/}" in
  ++ [[ -z /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5 ]]
  ++ shift
  ++ chruby_use /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5 ''
  ++ [[ ! -x /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ export RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5
  ++ RUBY_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5
  ++ export RUBYOPT=
  ++ RUBYOPT=
  ++ export PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  ++ PATH=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
  +++ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -
  ++ eval 'export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby;
  export RUBY_VERSION=2.6.5;
  export GEM_ROOT="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0";'
  +++ export RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ RUBY_ENGINE=ruby
  +++ export RUBY_VERSION=2.6.5
  +++ RUBY_VERSION=2.6.5
  +++ export GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  +++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  ++ ((  0 != 0  ))
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200229-17441-1xumk3r17441' as your home directory temporarily.
  + '[' false == true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200229-17445-s2fu1t17445' as your home directory temporarily.
  rake aborted!
  ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2020-02-29T14:56:22.022Z] INFO  [3700]  - [Application update app-61df-200229_165115@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-29T14:56:22.022Z] INFO  [3700]  - [Application update app-61df-200229_165115@2/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-29T14:56:22.022Z] INFO  [3700]  - [Application update app-61df-200229_165115@2/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2020-02-29T14:56:22.023Z] INFO  [3700]  - [Application update app-61df-200229_165115@2] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
```

I tried setting a `master.key`, tried setting `secret_base_key` through ENV, but neither worked.

Despite pushing my environment with a `master.key`, it never persists in my SSH environment.

I also am unable to run `rails credentials:edit` in my SSH environment and running it locally then deploying to production does nothing, the changes never persist in the SSH server, the `master.key` is never generated despite all the settings being correct.

I've been stuck on this for four days, and am curious if I should move onto another platform, perhaps Heroku or Google?

Comment: In your `production.rb` file how is the `secret_key_base` being set? Could you include this code?

Comment: config.secret_key_base = ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Please write a usable title that is NOT full of tags.

Comment: Do not add code to your question using a comment. Edit your question and add that information where you would have if you'd included it initially. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can tell what's changed. Adding code in comments forces us to read every comment on a page and try to piece together the information.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks a lot! i'll use this as reference for any further questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different ways you can set the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` configuration variable.

1. Set this variable through the Elastic Beanstalk console environment variables. From your EB environment, click Configuration -> Software, and add an environment variable for `SECRET_KEY_BASE` (all caps).
2. Set the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` variable through the Elastic Beanstalk console environment variable configuration, and set the `secret_key_base` in your encrypted credentials file:

   - From your EB environment, click Configuration -> Software, and add an environment variable for `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` (all caps). This value should be the one that is in your `master.key` file.
   - Locally, run `rails credentials:edit`, and add the following line to your file:

   ```
   secret_key_base: substitute-your-very-long-secret-key-here
   ```

   Save, close, and commit the file. Deploy these changes to your Elastic Beanstalk environment.